# Web scraping tools and software available for free

Tags: gratis, scraping

What are some free ready-to-use web scraping applications?

Usage: Monitoring online product prices, vendors, top 20 online market places in Asia and comparing price developments.

I am a beginner using [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) and have a [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) setup.

I am looking for the following capabilities and functions:

- Browser interface, search function
- Input: Search words (product, brand)
- Output: vendor webpage, product price, and product pictures

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Answer (score 1):

For Python, my favorite is hands down [Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy).

If you want a GUI for it, [Portia](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia).

^^ If you want a GUI to install and run that [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) container:
https://kitematic.com/

Comment: If that is more than you're comfortable with: https://www.webscraper.io/

Comment: Scrapy is the answer, although it might be worth looking at Beautiful Soup

Comment: `https://kitematic.com/` redirects to the generic `https://www.docker.com/`. What is/was it?